# Integrating PayPal's PHP REST API SDK, still a good idea?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently integrating the PayPal's PHP REST API SDK. However, reading the documentation and the code I've found that the method to get the payer's shipping details is deprecated. Also, PayPal is encouraging to use Braintree's SDK to process credit card payments. Also, the git repository seems to be very quiet.
Thus, here are my two questions :

1. Is PayPal abandoning the REST API ? Is it still a good idea to use its deprecated methods to return the payer's shipping details ? Or is there another way I haven't discovered yet ?
2. Is PayPal still a good option for guest credit card payments ? Or do I risk having my e-commerce down suddenly one day ?

I am aware of other solutions that have PayPal support such as Braintree. However, my busisness isn't large enough for them to accept my application so I am stuck with PayPal (coming from Shopify and going independant)

Thanks a lot for your time !

LazyTanuki